# Textbox text to data template UWP

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I am trying to add the text entered to a list view in UWP. However all I am seeing is button.

[image]

The picture should show what was entered, BINXXX. How do you bind textbox text to the data template for a listview? Here is my current XML.

```
        <ListView x:Name="binListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="411" Margin="370,139,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="388">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Width="32" Height="32" Tag="{Binding}" Click="Delete_Item" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Button.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/rubbish-bin.png">
                            </ImageBrush>
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="Whatever my textbox says" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to set an ItemSource property for your list view bound to a list on the c# side, which you would add to in some sort of event from the TextBox such as KeyDown or Keyup `void TextBoxKeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyDowEventArgs args){ boundList.add(TextBoxNameHere.Text); }`